# How to find element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been using selenium for a little bit now and have been stuck on this issue for the past few hours. It seems really simple but I just can't seem to figure out a proper execution. I basically am trying to select a shoe size based on the user's input. Here are a few of the buttons I am trying to sort through as well as the surrounding HTML.

```
<p class="checkbox-size">
    <input type="radio" value="500" id="super_attribute[150]_500" name="super_attribute[150]" class="product_attribute">
    <label for="super_attribute[150]_500">
        <span id="label_eu0" class="label_hidden"> 38.5</span>
        <span id="label_us0" class="label_show"> 6</span>
        <span id="label_uk0" class="label_hidden"> 5.5</span>
        <span id="label_cm0" class="label_hidden"> 24</span>
    </label>
</p>
```

The specific button I am trying to press is this one:

```
<label for="super_attribute[150]_137">
    <span id="label_eu10" class="label_hidden"> 45</span>
    <span id="label_us10" class="label_show"> 11</span>
    <span id="label_uk10" class="label_hidden"> 10</span>
    <span id="label_cm10" class="label_hidden"> 29</span>
</label>
```

Now I tried many different methods of searching then clicking one of the buttons but nothing has worked yet. Any suggestions? Here is what I am currently using to try and find and click the button:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='11']").click()
```

Looking back I might have not provided the correct code for the buttons, so here is a snapshot of the inspect element as well as the actual [page](https://www.overkillshop.com/en/nike-air-max-1-ah8145-102.html#product_tabs_options) if you want to go check it out for yourself. I am trying to click the size buttons. [Button inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xypz.png)

Solved! 
Here is the code I ended up using.

```
sizes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('checkbox-size')
for size in sizes:
    if size.text in [usersize]:
        size.click()
        print colored('Carted size %s'%(size.text), 'green')
        break
    continue
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Use button=find_element_by_xpath(//*[@class="label_show"])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so here is what I ended up using which solved the issue. I made a list of all the web elements with the class `'checkbox-size'` then traversed that list to to find the correct size, and then click on that element. 
Here is the code:

```
    sizes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('checkbox-size')
for size in sizes:
    if size.text in [usersize]:
        size.click()
        print colored('Carted size %s'%(size.text), 'green')
        break
    continue
```

Comment: You are looping through every size to find the right one. My answer will find it in a single search... no looping involved.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your approach.

1. You are trying to click the `INPUT` when you need to click a `SPAN`
2. The sizes on the page contain some amount of whitespace which makes your strict string comparison, value='11', not work. Also the contained text is not considered a `value`.
3. Another issue you will run into is that all of the sizes aren't displayed. The sizes displayed is controlled by the links above the sizes, EU, US, UK, and CM. The ones that are displayed have `class="label_show"` so you will want to specify that in your answer or you will attempt to click elements that are not visible which will throw an exception. (Selenium only interacts with visible elements by design).

With all this, we can build the following XPath

```
//span[@class='label_show'][normalize-space(.)='10']
```

If it were me, I would throw this in a function that pass in the desired size as a string and insert that parameter into the above XPath to make this much more reusable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Here is the code I ended up using it works pretty well for this application.                                                                
`for size in sizes:
  if size.text in [usersize]:
   size.click()
   print colored('Carted size %s'%(size.text), 'green')
   break
  continue`                                                                                                     Sorry about the formatting, I don't know why it won't show the indents and different lines. It's basically a for loop which finds all the sizes, finds the correct size, then clicks it.

Comment: I added this code into the original question if you would like to take a look at it properly formatted. @JeffC

Answer (score -1):

Try the below locator(xpath):

```
.//span[contains(@id,'label_eu') and text()=' 40']
```

Comment: This won't work in many cases because you are expecting the EU sizes to be displayed and the single space in the size won't always work because not all sizes contain a single space. Also your XPath starts with `.` which is not necessary.

Comment: basically you are trying to click input filed that you are not suppose to  and . in the start of xpath introduces a relative location path, starting at the context node helps in identifying the xpath quickly.

Comment: You can try this xpath //input[@value=11]/parent::p//span[@class='label_show']

Comment: It's only relative if you are starting your search at another element. In this case (and OP's case) you aren't so it makes no sense. `value` has no meaning with this HTML because you need to click a `SPAN`.

Comment: I didn't understand harm in using the . in the start of xpath and without using value attribute i didn't find any unique attribute to make a unique xpath.
By the way , xpath what you have suggested before is giving 2 matching nodes.

Comment: One possible solution would be , iterating over all the elements of checkbox-size and click the required element.